# Trying to print all the elements of a page to the console

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to print all the h3 of my website into a list within the console but its not working? I've even tried it on a random online site to check if it would work and it doesn't make a difference... The irony is its the same code i've used before to do it on my website but It's not working

Heres what im running in the console

```
for(i = 0; i < 300; i++) {console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("H3") 
[i].innerHTML)};
```

Heres a sample of what my website html would be...

```
<h3>Hello</h3>
<h3>There</h3>
<h3>My</h3>
<h3>Fried</h3>
```

What Im trying to get to print to the console...
Hello
There
My
Friend

I've tried adjusting the upper limit of 300, I could do i.e document.getElementsByTagName["H3"].arrayLength or whatever and store that in a value as upper limit but thats besides the point. Its not working...

Comment: do you realize getElementsByTagName has a length? `var h3s = document.getElementsByTagName('h3'); console.log(h3s.length);`

Answer (score 1):

You are querying the DOM on each iteration instead of getting all elements, and then iterating them:

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName("H3")

for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {console.log(elements[i].innerHTML)}
```

```html
<h3>Hello</h3>
<h3>There</h3>
<h3>My</h3>
<h3>Fried</h3>
```

You can also use `document.querySelectorAll()` and convert the NodesList to an array using `Array.from()`:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('h3')

const arr = Array.from(elements, el => el.innerHTML)

console.log(arr.join(' '))
```

```html
<h3>Hello</h3>
<h3>There</h3>
<h3>My</h3>
<h3>Fried</h3>
```